# How do I run through a List (Specifically an ArrayList) of type Object (Like a class) and collect a specific String in each Object

Tags: java, list, arraylist

So, I'm trying to do something pretty simple. Basically, I am suppose to add a subscriber to a list of subscribers. If the subscriber is already there, I don't add it, if the subscriber isn't already there, I add it. And another option to remove an existing subscriber. I was able to get this to work just fine using the .indexOf command to search through the different names. However, this was all in one class, my main class.

I then realized that I also need to be able to send a message to all subscribers and store that message in another String connected to each subscriber. I understood this to mean I needed to make another class called Subscriber, and have a String called name, and a String called message. And then just have an ArrayList full of the Subscriber class objects. However, since I now have 2 Strings connected to each object, I couldn't use the search function of a List anymore.

For instance doing something like this:

```
List<Subscriber> subscribers = new ArrayList<Subscriber>();
if (subscribers.indexOf(newSub) != -1){
subscribers.setName(newSub);}
```

Would not work.

In this code, newSub is the user input that I am trying to cross reference to all other names, and the setName is a method in my Subscriber class that I am trying to set this name to.

First off, it gives me an error saying that setName cannot be found, and then I also thought that it wouldn't be able to search through the different subscribers with .indexOf because each has 2 different Strings attached to them.

I am very stuck on this, I have no idea what to do with it, any and all help is welcome and much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the equals method in your Subscriber class to only compare the name string, so that contains or indexOf still work:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj == this)
        return true;
    try {
        Subscriber s = (Subscriber)obj;
        return name.equals(s.getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

EDIT to include OP's clarification:
Once the above is added to the Subscriber class, then the algorithm can be executed in the main program as follows:

```
List<Subscriber> subscribers = new ArrayList<Subscriber>();
String newSub;
// set newSub from user input via Scanner

Subscriber myNewSub = new Subscriber(newSub, "new message");
if (!subscribers.contains(myNewSub)){
    subscribers.add(myNewSub);
}
```

Comment: So in my main code, I'd have something like "subscribers.equals(__?__)" not quite sure what would go in the paraenthesis. And then when you say "(obj == this)", what does "this" refer to? And also, I've rarely used try-throw-catch commands. I'm not entirely sure how they work, they were never explained to me very well?

Comment: No, adding this method to your Subscriber class would make it so that you could do something like 
if (!subscribers.contains(newSub)) {subscribers.add(newSub);}

Comment: OH, I didn't know this, thank you very much, I'll give it a go.

Comment: the obj == this line is testing to see if the passed in object is the same instance of the object. So if I did Subscriber s = new Subscriber(name, message), and then did something like s.equals(s) it would return true. Even if I later did s.setName("somethingelse") it would still return true, because it's the same instance of the object.

Comment: Ok, however, when I do "subscribers.add(newSub);", that newSub is a String, not an Object, so it doesn't work does it? newSub is the users input of a name, and the name is being cross referenced with all other names.

Comment: here, the try catch is going to make sure that if somehow this method got called on an object that wasn't a Subscriber, then it would return false. Any time you cast an object to a specific class, it's good practice to surround this with a try/catch, because if you then attempt to access a class variable, like i do with name.equals() on a failed cast, this will throw an error and cause your program to stop running.

Comment: Ah ok, so first you need to create a new Subscriber object from the newSub string, and use that. So:
Subscriber myNewSub = new Subscriber(newSub, message);
if(!subscribers.contains(myNewSub) {
    subscribers.add(myNewSub);
}

Comment: Oh, I see, okay. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The correct use would be like this :

```
List<Subscriber> subscribers = new ArrayList<Subscriber>();
if (!subscribers.contains(newSub)) {
    subscribers.add(newSub);
}
```

Comment: But the problem still exists with the subscribers.add(newSub);. Because I want to send newSub to the method I have created in my Subscriber class. Which are called setName, and setMessage. How do I distinguish between the two methods when using .add?

Comment: @Myles What? `newSub` is a `Subscriber` *instance*. Why do you need to invoke mutators here? You do need to override `equals` ***in* `Subscriber`** (which you did not post). If you also override `hashCode`, you could probably use a `HashSet` and `Set`.

Comment: I agree with @ElliottFrisch

Comment: @Myles you cannot use setName() function with subscribers! It is a list. you have to use setName() with newSub!

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for the clarification, I'll look into it.

Comment: Also, there might be a confusion as to what newSub is. In my full code, newSub is a Scanner used to collect the user input, nothing more. I am trying to send newSub into one of the methods of my Subscriber class. Like "public void setName (String newSub) {
               this.name = newSub;}"
Hopefully this clears up the confusion?

Comment: So what I was doing with original code I posted, was searching through all of subscribers for the String stored in "newSub" to see if it matched any that were there before. And it worked fine, it worked how I thought it would. But that was before I created the Subscriber class.

Comment: @Myles if it helped you. please upvote and accept the answer

Comment: Well that's what I'm saying, Elliot Frisch is saying that newSub is a Subscriber instance, which is incorrect, in my code, it's a String connected to a Scanner. All it holds is user input.

Answer (score 0):

`subscribers` is not Subscriber, it is a list that can contain subscriber. So, if you are trying to access Subscriber's method setName, you have to pick one of the item of the list and call setName.

How about creating a static field in Subscriber class and assign the new name to it? If you don't want to do that, you have to loop through every subscriber as shown below.

```
List<Subscriber> subscribers = new ArrayList<Subscriber>();
if (subscribers.indexOf(newSub) != -1){
    subscribers.add(newSub);
    for (Subscriber sub: subscribers){
        sub.setName(newSub.getName());
    }
}
```

Also is newSub is a string or a Subscriber type? That will influence lot of things. If it is a string that matches the name of a subscriber, above code doesn't work, you will have to loop through each element of the list and see if it matches subscriber. But then again if you are changing all names in previous loops, you can just check first element's name instead of validating all subscriber names.

Comment: Ok, looping through wouldn't be too big of a problem since I don't expect there to be many subscribers added to test how big it can go. I'm still used to the for loop in the style of "for (int i = 0; i < ___; i++)", I know yours does basically the same thing, I'm just not quite sure I understand the internals of your for loop parameters. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: This is called foreach construct. It will take each element of the array list and assign it to `sub` and run the loop body. It will do this for all elements in the array list. pick first and assign it to sub and run loop body, pick second and assign it to sub and run loop body... it goes on until last element of the array list.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. These always confused me in class and I always forgot how the layout looked.

Comment: Oh, to anwer your question under the code, newSub is a String type. It's connected to a Scanner that just takes input from the user. Like, the user is inputting the name that they want to add, and I'm checking to see if it matches a name of any other subscriber. But the subscribers are suppose to have a Name attached to them, and a Message attached to them, I was confused on how to only set the Name and not the Message, or vice versa.